# Difference between Foundation.h and cocoa.h

Tags: cocoa

m new to objective C tel me why sometimes it shows foundation.h and sometimes cocoa.h in the AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 7):

`Cocoa.h` includes `Foundation.h`, `AppKit.h`, and `CoreData.h`, and nothing else.